# Goals: counting traffic if a URL includes a parameter or not

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I'm new to goals in Google Analytics and I need to set up a bunch of goals the URLs below.

**I have these four URLs:** I've set up the URLs without the? Itb parameters as goals inside Google Analytics where the value equals the relative URL

- au-uken/this-part-of-the-URL-is-common-to-many-URLs/
- au-uken/this-part-of-the-URL-is-common-to-many-URLs/?It=239011
- au-uken/this-part-of-the-URL-is-common-to-many-URLs/changing-lives/1/
- au-uken/this-part-of-the-URL-is-common-to-many-URLs/changing-lives/1/?it=239011

**My questions:**

1. I am unsure however if the goal will count traffic if the? It parameter is included, as I would like to count traffic for each goal URL whether a URL includes the? It parameter or not

   2. If it won't traffic for for a goal if a URL includes the? It parameter, which regular expression can I use that would achieve what I want to do? (I can't use 'begins with' because there is a whole part of the URL that is common to several URLs that I need goals for. I'm totally new to regular expressions so not sure how to achieve what I want to do. )

Hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the four goals as distinct goals then you would need an exact match goal for the first and third goals you have, and for the second and fourth goals with the query parameter you would need to configure them as regex

```
^au\-uken\/common_part\/\?it=.*$
```